# How to get the median based on column headings?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Let's say we have:

```
EPS    Sentiment    Revenue  Sentiment     Formula1?     Formula2?

10     3%            20       5%           F1a           F2a
9      6%            30       4%           F1b           F2b
```

I have more than 600 columns, and this is a simplified column. I have more than 150 "Sentiment" columns.

For F1a and F1b, I want to get 73% percentile on sentiment data on the same row, i.e., if column heading is "Sentiment", then include data in F1 formula to get percentile.

For F2a and F2b, I want to get median on sentiment data on the same row, i.e., if column heading is "Sentiment", then include data in F1 formula to get percentile.

As I have 2000 over rows, I would like to copy both F1a and F2a downwards all the way to F1z and F2z and more.

What formulas shall I use for F1 and F2?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very elegant answer, however it will give the results that were asked for concerning the "simplified column". It assumes that the actual data is arranged in such a way that the "sentiment" columns are spaced at regular intervals. It will require "helper columns", fortunately your data is only making use of 600 of the over 1600 columns available.

For the "simplified column" answer:

- 1) place the formula `=INDEX($A2:$D2,(COLUMN()-7)*2+2)` in cell G2
- 2)    pull the fill handle to copy the formula over to cell H2
- 3) with both    cells still selected double click the fill handle to
  send the formula    down
- 4) place the formula `=PERCENTILE.INC(G2:H2,0.73)` in cell E2 (I
  used the .INC version, however you may need to use the .EXC version
  depending on how the data is being interpreted)
- 5) double click the    fill handle to send the formula down
- 6) place the formula    `=MEDIAN(G2:H2)` in cell F2
- 7) double click the fill handle to send the formula down

[image]